# How to get an array value from the query in Yii 1.1

Tags: php, yii, yii1.x

```
$us= Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->select('default_number_of_devices')
    ->from('user')
    ->where('id=1')
    ->queryRow();
echo "$us";
```

I should have got one value instead of `array` type because `id` is unique. But  `$us` appears to be an array instead of single number.

Comment: Is that a quote from someone important?

Comment: when i write <?php echo "$us"; ?>  display is (array)
I would like to insert a single number like 3 => fill in the default_number_of_devices ricord because it uses where id 1, and only appears one digit

Comment: First you should understand that you can't echo an array.

Comment: the above query is to define select default_number_of_devices from user where id = 1;
if in sql only appears one number like number 3
but when I roll over $us just write the array instead of number 3

Comment: It you want to array instead of single column value, then you should try `queryAll()`. And please ask you questions in proper way with exact output and expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`queryScalar()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#queryScalar-detail) if you want to get single value from single column:

```
$us = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->select('default_number_of_devices')
    ->from('user')
    ->where('id=1')
    ->queryScalar();
echo $us;
```

`queryRow()` returns first row from query. And since row usually contains multiple columns, array is expected format (each element of array contains value of single column).

Comment: it's use  ->queryScalar(); and not queryRow()

Comment: @kagami there are three ways to fetch the data. First one is `queryScalar()` which returns just the single value from query, which you wanted here. Second one is `queryRow()` which returns a single row from query as `array`. Last, there is `queryAll()` which returns one array with all rows and columns. Cheers!